# Marionette js: how to render an HTML5/javascript video player

Tags: dom, html5-video, marionette

Some popular, commercially available HTML5 video players are essentially big chunks of JavaScript.  JWPlayer is one.  I use a different one but it's similar in set up.

These players embed in a way that seems out of step with client-side MVC frameworks in general.  The players want to render themselves to the DOM.  You instantiate a player object and pass a DOM element to it's constructor.  Like...

```
    mediaPlayer = new CommercialVideoPlayer("some-place-in-DOM");
```

The player then renders itself to "some-place-in-DOM".

Doesn't that conflict with view rendering in marionette - with the region manager showing views?

In other words this "player rendering itself" thing seems, on my first look, to conflict with the notion that marionette wants to render.  It wants its region manager to map views to DOM elements.  It doesn't want some player sticking things in the DOM.

It wants to do...

```
    someRegion.show(someView);
```

I'm not wrapping my brain around where my HTML5 video player goes in there?  Inside a view?

When I put it inside a view and then attempt to show it, like...

```
    videoRegion.show(videoView);//media player is inside videoView
```

...I get nothing because marionette's region manager and the player are fighting over who gets to render where.

I think I just lack a conceptual understanding of what marionette js would want me to do with this media player.  I'm looking for an understanding and a best practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marionette region managers want to display Marionette views. Period. They don't care about what those views do.

In other words, you can have your view create DOM element, then show the video player, something like:

```
var VideoView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  template: _.template('<div id="video-player"></div>'),

  onShow: function(){
    this.mediaPlayer = new CommercialVideoPlayer("some-place-in-DOM");
  }
});

var myVideoView = new VideoView();

videoRegion.show(myVideoView);
```

The above is untested pseudo code, but should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Seems logical. Doesn't work though because although Marionette doesn't care what the views do, the player does.  It doesn't want to render itself unless its container div (id="video-player) exists in the DOM.  In onShow it hasn't been inserted into the DOM yet.  I've tested this by removing marionette altogether and just embedding the player in a plain html page.  If I remove the player's container div, "video-player", I get the same error I get if I run the marionette onShow code above.  This is one of those cases where two third party libraries are at odds.  Kind of a chicken and egg problem

Comment: I need some marionette way to render my template before my player tries to find that container element.

Comment: My bad.  Other small error.  Think this might be working.  Checking now.

Comment: Yes.  This works.  I had forgotten to style the extra div marionette wraps around your itemView.  By default it has no size so my video player was not appearing.  Added className: "fullsize" to the itemView and gave it some size in there.  All good.  Thanks much for the insight.